# After browser back button load last search

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have own plugin in October CMS what have a `onFilter()` function whats return and displays partials with data. When user click on name it redirect him to a detail page. And when user click back button in browser I want to display his last search.

I tried something like `Session::push('data', $data)` in `onFilter()` method and `Session::get('data')` in `onInit()` but it didnt work. `$data` is a list of pubs.

Had anyone same problem?

**Edit**

```
public function onFilter()
{
    $result =
            Lounge::filterLounge($categories, $tags, $regions, $paidIds, $price_from, $search);

    Session::put('nameFilter', $result);

    return [
            '#list' => $this->renderPartial('loungelist::list.htm', [
                'list_data' => $result])
                ];
}
```

```
    public function getNameFilter() {
        $nameFilter = Session::get('nameFilter');
        return $nameFilter;
    }
```

In partial .htm

```
{% set list_data = __SELF__.getNameFilter() %}
{% for lounge in list_data %}
{{ lounge.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not familiar with October, but have you tried saving them to localStorage or something via JavaScript? Another easy approach would be to use query params

Comment: Can I use it even if it redirects to another page? I am quite begginer.

Comment: That could be where you're getting caught up. If you jumping domains, that won't work.

Comment: Domains not, only pages on single domain.

Comment: You should be fine then. `localStorage` is a good solution to your use case here.

Comment: You can also check out `window.history` api. Not exactly the most straightforward thing to use, but certainly reliable and aligning with what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Answer (score 0):

As @mwilson mentions I would use window.history on the front end with the `pushstate()` function so that when each filter is changed you push state including query strings before firing to php to get the filtered content. I have done this before and works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You should post more code for us to be more helpful. I am assuming you are using a component. Are you using ajax? Session will do the job.

In your component.php put `onNameFilter()` event you can push the data into the session with `Session::put('nameFilter' $data);`. I suggest using more specific labels for your events and keys so I chose 'nameFilter'.

You will want to use a method in your component.php to call the session.

```
public function getNameFilter() {
    $nameFilter = Session::get('nameFilter');
    return $nameFilter;
}
```

Now in your partial.htm you can set the name filter data and access it as long as it is in the session:

```
 {% set nameFilterData = __SELF__.getNameFilter() %}
```

**EDIT TO SHOW REFLECTED CODE**

I don't understand how it works the first time. What does your CMS Page look like? How do you show the filter the "first time"?

Your CMS Page has `{% component 'something' %}` right? Then in your default.htm file you have `{% partial __SELF__~'::list %}`?

In your partial you will need to display the list_data. Does this show anything?

```
{% for list in list_data %}
    {{ list_data.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes I tried use smth like this but it doesn't work. When I save to the session and then redirect to another page (another component) and then go back in browser it doesn't load anything.

Comment: You can't say you have tried something like this and not provide any code in your question. The answer I gave you works flawlessly. Have you tried to do a `dd($variable)` to see if your code is actually working? `onInit()` won't work on partials. Provide clear cut code so we can help you.

Comment: I added code to my question, it works only on first time. So when I search first time and try to display this from session it works. When I refresh the page it doesn't.

Comment: In your partial htm this is all you have? `{% set list_data = __SELF__.getNameFilter() %}` wouldn't you need `{% for list in list_data %}` ? Check my answer I will update it to reflect your code.

Comment: Yes of course I have, it was only for example. I tried Session::has('nameFilter') and it returns false. I guess it works only within one function.

Comment: Can you try to do a die and dump `dd(Session::all());` Unless you have something deleting the session it should last for at least 2hours I think is default time.

Comment: This is after put
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "Tl8dz3WWGxbv2I1n0rB78g31Wq26bVNi4WD84SL8"
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "nameFilter" => []
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "locale" => "cs"
  "fallback_locale" => "en"
  "widget" => array:5 [▶]
  "cosi" => null
]

Comment: When I put into session in onRun() it displays but when I put it into session in onFilter() it doesnt really save it.

Comment: So you did `Session::put('nameFilter', $result);` in onRun(). Try to remove it then see if session stays.

Comment: Then we are looking at a function that is flushing the session or the time of your session. If you go to config -> session there should be a lifetime parameter and a on close clear session parameter. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Probably not the problem. `'lifetime' => 120, 'expire_on_close' => false`